# How to recieve webhook posts in Java servlet/Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, webhooks

Does someone have a link to or an example of a java servlet that can receive 3rd party webhook posts?  My web app is a collection of servlet/jsps hosted on Tomcat, (build in an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project).  I have searched in vain for a simple example of a servlet/setup that can receive webhooks.  Specifically, I need to receive webhooks from applications such as Jira and Prefect.  On receipt of the webhooks, I need to trigger actions, such as update a MySQL database.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a servlet that receives HTTP requests and processes the event payload from a triggered webhook? Or are you asking if something already exists so that you don't have to read documentation from Jira or Prefect to know how to parse the event payload in your servlet? It's not clear what you need help with.

Comment: Thanks. I need to know how to know how to write a servlet that receives HTTP requests and processes the event payload from a triggered webhook. I know how to parse the payload.

Comment: You create a servlet, implement the `doPost` method, get the data from the request, most likely by calling `request.getReader()` or depending on how you receive the data maybe even `request.getParameter()`, then do something with the data. You need to make your question more specific, because you are now basically asking how to write a servlet that handles requests, which is extremely generic.

Comment: Many thanks! I don't know why I didn't try this in the first place. I was under the mistaken impression that I had to do something 'special' to make this work- start a listener, configure a Container, set up Web Services, I don't know what. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do need a sevlet container, like Tomcat. But you already have that. So I suggest you read a bit about how to build a servlet. You can start on the SO provided page for the servlets tag, here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info. Another good resource, if you need to troubleshoot is this: https://servlets.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz